# Function being called twice - once with correct value, once with wrong value

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

This is a first post and also I am new to coding, so hopefully the question is clear enough.

I am doing a basic JavaScript exercise. The program is working largely as I need it to except one problem.

The program populates a series of alerts. For example, if you select maths and then enter: 1, +, 1 in the next three alerts it returns "Your answer is 2" (which is correct). However, then, it subsequently show the 'Uh oh! Problem!!', which isn't right.

I can't work out why this is happening?

I have pasted the relevant code below. Also, a https://jsfiddle.net/poc4kzm9/ with all the code is here.

```
//////////////// MATHS CALCULATOR //////////////////////////

// logic for maths calculation
function mathCalculate(operator, firstNumber, secondNumber) {
  console.log(operator);
  if (operator === '+') {
    add(firstNumber, secondNumber);
  } else if (operator === '-') {
    subtract(firstNumber, secondNumber);
  } else if (operator === '/') {
    divide(firstNumber, secondNumber);
  } else if (operator === '*') {
    multiply(firstNumber, secondNumber);
  } else if (operator === 'sq') {
    power(firstNumber, secondNumber);
  } else if (operator ==='sqrt') {
    squareRoot(firstNumber);
  } else {
    alert('Uh oh! Problem!!');
  }
}

// collect required values for math
function mathSetup() {
  // Set intial values for math calculator
  const firstNumber = prompt('What is your first number?');
  const operator = prompt('Which operator would you like to use? (+, -, /, *, sq, sqrt)');
  let secondNumber;

  // No need for a second number if sqrt-ing the first value
  if (operator !== 'sqrt') {
    secondNumber = prompt('What is your second number?');
  }
  mathCalculate(operator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
}

// The various functions by operator, one for each operator
function add(a,b) {
  alert('Answer is ' + (parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b)));
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The bit of code that causes the issue is not included in your question. You should not call `mathCalculate()` without parameters in your run loop, just after `mathSetup()`. `mathSetup()` calls it properly later. https://jsfiddle.net/poc4kzm9/2/

Comment: Amazing, thank you! That makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `mathCalculate` method twice.

First time is in `mathSetup` and another one is your main loop in switch. Second time you call it without parameters. Thats why you get alert about problem.

To fix this you have to remove `matchCalculate` from `switch`. Another way is to return data from `mathSetup` and use it in `mathCalculate`

I also made fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5bh9ndhc/

I returned data from `mathSetup` and I use it in `mathCalculate`:

```
const [operator, firstNumber, secondNumber] = mathSetup();
mathCalculate(operator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
```

Note that I used destructuring assignmen. This syntax is part of ECMAScript 2015 so it will work only in a few modern browsers.

UPD: I highly recommend use `debugger` keyword in such cases. Your code has many lines and I see it first time in my life, but because of `debugger` keyword and Chrome Devtools I was able to find the mistake in 30 seconds.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.

Comment: I added fiddle how you can return and pass values between functions

Comment: I also added note about `debugger` keyword and devtools

Comment: Great, thanks. Debugger is very useful, I wasn't aware of this keyword. The method you use to pass values between functions better practice (aside for ES 2015 caveat) than my method of calling the function within a function?

Comment: I don't think that the _words_ are better. I think that function with name setup have to do setup and function with name calculate have to do calculations. I think its about design. Your code will work too perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You are calling calculate function twice

One inside the setup function

```
function mathSetup() {
  // Set intial values for math calculator
  const firstNumber = prompt('What is your first number?');
  const operator = prompt('Which operator would you like to use? (+, -, /, *, sq, sqrt)');
  let secondNumber;

  // No need for a second number if sqrt-ing the first value
  if (operator !== 'sqrt') {
    secondNumber = prompt('What is your second number?');
  }
  mathCalculate(operator, firstNumber, secondNumber);
}
```

and after setup

```
  mathSetup();
  mathCalculate();
```

Remove calculate function from switch case at that point you don't have information about calculation. Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/ezmhc0ff/